# mysql query that looks for a value in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering if i can put something in my query which searches for a word within a string.  For example, if i have a field named user_purchased, i want to query it and pull only records where the word 'dog' exists within the string.

I know i can do this using php like this

```
(!stristr($row['user_purchased'], 'dog'))
```

BUT, i'm wondering if i can do this in the query itself instead and that this will perhaps speed up performance.

Thanks in advance for help on this

Comment: Please be aware that all the answers you're getting involving `LIKE '%foo%'` or `INSTR` force a full scan. This will be slow if your table is big. They can *not* do an index lookup.

Comment: thanks what would i use instead if i wanted to maximize speed.  my table is big so speed is an issue

Comment: if speed is critical, you need an indexing solution such as MySQL fulltext or Sphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LIKE:

```
WHERE your_col LIKE '%dog%'
```

If you want better performance you could look at a [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html). This uses a FULLTEXT index to quickly find the matching rows.

Comment: thank you, this makes sense.  how would i change this for searching for results that DID NOT have the word dog in them?

Comment: figure this out, use NOT LIKE

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, you can use INSTR(str,substr)

Quote from the MySql manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

```
INSTR(str,substr)

Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str. This is the same as the two-argument form of LOCATE(), except that the order of the arguments is reversed.

mysql> SELECT INSTR('foobarbar', 'bar');
        -> 4
mysql> SELECT INSTR('xbar', 'foobar');
        -> 0
This function is multi-byte safe, and is case sensitive only if at least one argument is a binary string.
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_purchased LIKE '%dog%';